# How exactly do I place an object in the middle of a landscape page?

Tags: positioning

I often have large tables or images that I try to put in the center of a landscape page. Using the `pdflscape` package I turn the page, but I then have to do a whole lot of playing and recompiling to figure out how to put the object in the middle (with `hspace` and `vspace`). Centering it does not work. These objects are often larger than the regular page margins allow, so in an ideal scenario I can remove the page margins (which I try doing using `newgeometry` but it doesn't really work), and use some sort of centering to put it automatically in the middle. Is there a way? Also, my caption remains off center using my current system.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[top=1.7cm, left=2.1cm, right=2.1cm, bottom=3.7cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}

\newgeometry{left=0.1cm,top=0.1cm,bottom=0.1cm,right=0.1cm}
\begin{figure}
  \vspace*{-8.0cm}
  \hspace*{-6.7cm}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=23cm]{black.jpg}
% Try for instance this image: http://i970.photobucket.com/albums/ae189/katiewilson1995/Untitled.jpg
  \caption{Here is a caption that should go in the center}
  \textit{(And this text should also be in the middle)}
\end{figure}
\restoregeometry
\end{landscape}
```

\end{document}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unrelated to landscape or images, if you want to centre something wider than the textblock you need to hide its width.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[top=1.7cm, left=2.1cm, right=2.1cm, bottom=3.7cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}


\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \makebox[0pt]{\includegraphics[width=23cm]{black.jpg}}

% Try for instance this image: http://i970.photobucket.com/albums/ae189/katiewilson1995/Untitled.jpg
  \caption{Here is a caption that should go in the center}
  \textit{(And this text should also be in the middle)}
\end{figure}

\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great, what a cool thing!! And suddenly everything works! Thanks!!